# Can anyone suggest best SSL VPN Gateway (Clientless 10 users)

Tags: vpn, hardware, gateway

Can anyone suggest best SSL VPN Gateway (Clientless 10 users)

Answer (score 2):

We use and like the Juniper SA-line of products.  We recommend them to our customers.

They are not cheap, though.

Comment: After having used the SSL VPN from Cisco (IOS & ASA), Juniper SA700, and F5.  I think their their no comparison Juniper wins hands down.  They do cost more but the SA700 with the upgraded feature set is great .

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a SonicWall SSL-VPN 2000, which is awesome. It is clientless,but also has the option of a client that you can download from the interface. Which runs on Windows,Mac, and Linux. This version will support 50 users, but they make a 200 series that will support less.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently demoing the [Barracuda SSL VPN](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/sslvpn_overview.php) appliance.  So far, it has been going great and we will most likely purchase multiple units.  One of our requirements was to use one-time passwords via SMS (essentially avoiding the cost of RSA for 2-factor authentication) and that is available with the Barracuda.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.cableguy.aspx) on Windows 2008 Server?  Works like champ and is easy to configure...  Works with the built-in Networking client in Microsoft Windows...

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Fortinet SoHo](http://www.fortinet.com/solutions/soho.html) solutions are also worth looking into. Starting with the Fortigate 50B, you get SSL VPN. Easy browser install, and very stable, from my experience.

Comment: +1 for the Fortigate 50B. It is cost effective, easy to configure through either CLI or Web GUI and it is rock solid stable.

Answer (score 0):

I love the Cisco ASA line of products.  I use them in a production environment and could not be happier.  Having said this, best is very subjective and depends entirely on your interpretation and what your particular needs are.

Answer (score 0):

It only took me an hour or so of Googling and trial n error to get a fully functioning ADITO solution running.  Another couple hrs to write my own user modules.  For 10 or so users, it's ideal.

Free.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Juniper solution.  We had the Cisco SSL VPN production before hand and Juniper is much easier to install, as well as having more features.  Now, I'm taking a look at Baracuda, but at the moment, I would say Juniper Secure Access Device.